# Repeating digits notation (e.g. 77777777)

Tags: notation

Is there a better way to write a number like 777777777777777? or 11111111?

Like a function f(3,7) meaning the digit 3 seven times: 3,333,333

Comment: This would probably be a good way: $\underbrace{7\cdots7}_{100}$. To typeset: `$\underbrace{7\cdots7}_{100}$`. (You'd have to make it clear from the context that this indicates repetition of digits and not a multiplication.)

Comment: all   ones is $\frac{10^n -1}{9},$   all digit $d$  would be $\; d  \; \; \frac{10^n -1}{9},$

Comment: Excellent! Thank you

Comment: Incidentally, these are called *repunits*; a search for that term will give you a lot more information.